# KNN in Tensorflow - Using Graph to predict unseen data

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, knn

Based on the following example of KNN in Tensorflow - what would be the best way to use the graph to "predict" the label of some unseen data?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# In this example, we limit mnist data
Xtr, Ytr = mnist.train.next_batch(5000) #5000 for training (nn candidates)
Xte, Yte = mnist.test.next_batch(200) #200 for testing

# tf Graph Input
xtr = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 784])
xte = tf.placeholder("float", [784])

# Nearest Neighbor calculation using L1 Distance
# Calculate L1 Distance
distance = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.add(xtr, tf.negative(xte))), reduction_indices=1)
# Prediction: Get min distance index (Nearest neighbor)
pred = tf.arg_min(distance, 0)

accuracy = 0.

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # loop over test data
    for i in range(len(Xte)):
        # Get nearest neighbor
        nn_index = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={xtr: Xtr, xte: Xte[i, :]})
        # Get nearest neighbor class label and compare it to its true label
        print("Test", i, "Prediction:", np.argmax(Ytr[nn_index]), \
            "True Class:", np.argmax(Yte[i]))
        # Calculate accuracy
        if np.argmax(Ytr[nn_index]) == np.argmax(Yte[i]):
            accuracy += 1./len(Xte)
    print("Done!")
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use an already trained model to predict something?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm asking.

Comment: Do you want to know how to save the current model and then load it to predict new data?

Comment: I know how to save and load @vijay m But I'm not sure how to use the model.  I believe this is the training step nn_index = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={xtr: Xtr, xte: Xte[i, :]})   But how do use the model on unseen data?  Or do we have to use this call every time as training dat ais required for KNN?

Comment: No idea why this is getting voted to be closed - it is a valid question

Comment: Still not clear what the problem is. You call 'sess.run(pred, feed_dict={xtr: unseen_dat, xte: unseen_data}' with new data.

Comment: mmmmmm  - I would have expected there was a way to pass mnist.test.next_batch(1) to predict the label

Comment: U can.. X, y = minst.test.next_batch(batch_size) and sess.run(pred, feed_dict={xtr: X, xte: y}

Comment: mmmmm - Cannot feed value of shape (1, 10) for Tensor 'Placeholder_17:0', which has shape '(784,)'

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by appending these lines to the end, inside the "with tf.Session() as sess:".

```
# Generate new (unseen) data
X, y = mnist.test.next_batch(1)

# Compute index of new data
nn_index = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={xtr: Xtr, xte: X[0, :]})

# Print the computed prediction 
print("Test", i, 
      "Prediction:", np.argmax(Ytr[nn_index]),
      "True Class:", np.argmax(y[0]))
```